# Fresh ubuntu is extremely laggy

Tags: 16.04, performance

I'm running a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 on my desktop. It's an i7 processor with 16gb ram and (two) GeForce GTX 560 Ti graphic cards. I'm also running it on a new 34" with 3440x1440.

The whole system feels kinda laggy, the mouse pointer has a small latency (not that annoying for my use) and editing in PhpStorm has a slight delay in typing (much annoying). Where should I start to troubleshoot? What can I do to try to find the bottleneck? I've looked at a application named ubuntu-tweak, but I could not find it in the apt.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Not an answer, but is the NVIDIA driver installed correctly ( not the open but the binary one ). Can you ( temporarily disable the second Nvidia card? Had similar behavior with NVidia cards when the driver was not correct or they where in a config with two cards ( mine being an onboard Intel)

Comment: I'm using `NVIDIA binary driver - version 361.42 from nvidia-361 (proprietary, tested)`, how do i disable a card, do i have to remove the physically SLI-bridge and maybe even the card, or can i do it in some settings?

Comment: I never had a dual NVidia setup. So I can not tell you if there is a software switch. Maybe the BIOS has to support this. In my case I could turn off the Intel card in the BIOS

Comment: I disabled the intel graphics in BIOS now, and it seems to have helped alot.  Feel free to add that as an answer. Thank you

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the second graphics card. In our setup this had a massive impact on performance and stability